# Git merge several branches and lose changes from one of them

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

In our work project we had several branches being (ultimately) merged together.

- A - master
- B - proof-of-concept
- C - feature-1
- D - feature-2
- E - feature-3

All branches are originally branched from A. B is never merged back into A, but the other branches can be. During a particular commit, all the changes from one branch got deleted.

- Commit C (change that disappeared later)
- C => A
- A => E (new branch)
- Commit E
- E => A
- A => D
- Commit D
- D => B (changes from C => A are lost)

The only conflict that shows in the log for any commit/merge was for an unrelated file. The required change can be seen in D, but not in B. The merge from D => B shows the same changes as Commit D, unless both commits are selected, in which case it shows that a lot of changes have been removed.

I'm viewing everything in SourceTree because I'm not very familiar with command line git.

The code couldn't be merged back in because it already was merged, then deleted and you don't want to apply the same history twice. I wasn't the one who did the merge, so I don't know exactly what was done and the team member doesn't have a lot of experience with git yet, so it's difficult to get details beyond what's in the log. We're all supposed to use SourceTree but it's possible that some people use a different tool or use git from the command line only.

How could the code have been deleted without either a conflict or showing up in the regular log? Is there an option to discard all changes while merging branches?

I'm happy to provide further details if anything isn't clear.

Comment: to see all commits: `git log --graph --oneline --decorate=short --all`.   Use: `git reflog` for more context.

Comment: It's not clear from your sketch if D and E were branched from latest of A, but let's assum they did. Was B ever rebased? the correct thing to do is first to rebase B over A, then merge D into B.

If you want to merge C and D without rebase, better use cherry-pick.